# Is $|x-2x_k|<\varepsilon$ for all $k>N$ sufficient to show a sequence is convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

I am about to start with a few mathematics courses next semester and I was hoping someone could help me out with the following question.

Suppose there is a real-valued sequence $(x_k)$ such that there is a number $x\in\mathbf{R}$ such that for any $\varepsilon>0$ there is a positive integer $N$ such that $|x-2x_k|<\varepsilon$ for all $k>N$.

My gut feeling says that this sequence is convergent, since the $x_k$ will become arbitrary close to $x$. Is there a neat way to write this down?

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, I would say this is exactly the definition of $\frac{x}{2}$ as the limit, so the answer is yes.

Comment: Is it because $|x-2x_k| = |\frac12 x-x_k|<\varepsilon/2$?

Comment: Yes, the sequence approaches $x/2$, rather than $x$.

Comment: @kevin After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the sequence $(x_{k})$ converges to $x/2$. To see this, note that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is some $N \geq 1$ such that
$|\frac{x}{2} - x_{k}| = \frac{1}{2}|x-2x_{k}| < \varepsilon$ for all $k \geq N$.